# How to extract href link from this given code using bettersoup. i have tried other results on stack overflow

Tags: html, django, django-views

i am trying to **scrape** magnetic link from website. I am trying Beautifulsoup. I'm using pycharm with env.

This is how the href elements I need look like:

```
<a href="magnet:?xt=urn:btih:e43d60c559d1efc77f0a884d45c603b48a8384cf&amp;dn=Tu+Hi+Mera+-+Jannat+2+%282012%29%5Bvbr-320kbps%5D+&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.op
enbittorrent.com%3A80&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969" title="Download this torrent using magnet"><img alt="
Magnet link" src="//www.thepiratebay.org/static/img/icon-magnet.gif"/></a>
```

Comment: Are there multiple links?

Comment: Please add HTML tags and example output.

Comment: Please post your question clearly and add relevant tags only. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<a href="magnet:?xt=urn:btih:e43d60c559d1efc77f0a884d45c603b48a8384cf&amp;dn=Tu+Hi+Mera+-+Jannat+2+%282012%29%5Bvbr-320kbps%5D+&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.op
enbittorrent.com%3A80&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969" title="Download this torrent using magnet"><img alt="
Magnet link" src="//www.thepiratebay.org/static/img/icon-magnet.gif"/></a>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

links = []
for tag in soup.find_all("a"):
    href = tag.attrs['href']
    if href.startswith("magnet"):
        links.append(href)

print(links)
```

Output:

```
['magnet:?xt=urn:btih:e43d60c559d1efc77f0a884d45c603b48a8384cf&dn=Tu+Hi+Mera+-+Jannat+2+%282012%29%5Bvbr-320kbps%5D+&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.op\nenbittorrent.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969']
```